# serving server side configurations to the front end, rails/angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

we have a rails/angular app and on the server side we have some configurations (app_config.yml which is then internalized into a the constant APP_CONFIG)

Would like to somehow share these configs with the front-end. Our 1st-try, naive approach was to expose it like any other data, ie. via the API

```
class ConfigurationController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: APP_CONFIG }
    end
  end
end
```

And then having a service which requests it

```
class ServerConfigurations {
  constructor($resource) {
    $resource('/configuration/1.json').get().$promise.then(configs => {
      this.configurations = configs;
    });
  }
}
```

However, this solution is pretty suboptimal - we end up having to wait for the request to finish and it get's really ugly to have to do that for the most basic configuration.

it would be ideal if the config were somehow batched up with the JS (like in the pipeline) and served with the JS. Not sure what the best approach to that might be ...

Answer (score -1):

We have often done this by rendering globally exposed config options in the HTML.

You can use a directive to render the config in your template.